# Dragging elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

when i drag multiple items and drop it to particular div it only take 1st element. Later when i checked in  console.log($(ui.draggable)) length was 1.

```
({selector:"", context:#1=({}), 0:#1#, length:1})  when i dragged 3 elements
```

please help where i have gone wrong??

http://jsfiddle.net/akkiys/Hkfh2/4/

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="drag" >
    <li id="1">one</li>  
    <li id="2">two</li>    
    <li id="3">three</li>  
    <li id="4">four</li> 
    <li id="5">five</li>        
</ul>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var selectedClass = 'ui-state-highlight',
    clickDelay = 600,
    // click time (milliseconds)
    lastClick, diffClick; // timestamps
$("#drag li")
// Script to deferentiate a click from a mousedown for drag event
.bind('mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mousedown") {
        lastClick = e.timeStamp; // get mousedown time
    } else {
        diffClick = e.timeStamp - lastClick;
        if (diffClick < clickDelay) {
            // add selected class to group draggable objects
            $(this).toggleClass(selectedClass);
        }
    }
}).draggable({
    scroll: false,
    revertDuration: 10,
    // grouped items animate separately, so   leave this number low
    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.helper.addClass(selectedClass);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        // reset group positions
        $('.' + selectedClass).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        });
    },
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        // set selected group position to main dragged object
        // this works because the position is relative to the starting position
        $('.' + selectedClass).css({
            top: ui.position.top,
            left: ui.position.left
        });


    }
});

$(".drop").droppable({


    drop: function(event, ui) {


        var droppableId = $(this).find('div.inner').attr("id");

        //var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");   // i need to retrive multiple id
        console.log($(ui.draggable))
        var m_id = [];

        $.each($(ui.draggable), function(i, e) {
            m_id.push(e.id);
            alert(m_id);
        });
        console.log(m_id);


    }
});
```

Comment: Using your jsFiddle, in chrome, I get an alert saying how many I dragged, and it says the correct number. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: @Grezzo please try to drag multiple items and check . I need all multiple values which i have dragged. I think your dragging single item.

Comment: What do you mean by "drag multiple items"? As soon as I let go, they move back up to where they were. Provide some exact steps and what you see vs want to see at each step.

Comment: As soon as we drop it revert back to its original position and i know. I need the Ids  when i dragging one or more items at once.

Comment: How do you drag more than one item at once?! Two mice? (joking) Are you perhaps trying to use multi-touch?

Comment: Yes your right by using multi touch i am selecting one or more time. Please see it on http://jsfiddle.net/akkiys/Hkfh2/4/

Comment: You can't drag/drop two items with multi touch and drop at exactly the same time; your touchend events are bound to be a few ms apart. Also, if I drag/drop one word, then another both words move on the second drag (perhaps this is your issue?). How can I drag them with another finger if they are already being dragged by my first finger. Again I'll ask: Please provide step by step instructions of what you are dragging, what you see, and what you want to see. If you don't provide these steps and what you want to see verses what you are seeing, I will not waste any more of my time trying to help.

Comment: Sorry, Sir have you ever tried google plus selecting multiple people 1st and then dragging to the circle. The same concept i am trying to do.

Comment: No, I have never used google plus. So how do you select multiple "people" using your script?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this question have died out since its been a year since its creation and latest contribution, but I just stumbled into it and thought Id try to contribute, even though Im a total newbie on these things. Hopefully someone will have some use of it.

What I can see is basically : Since you are dragging ALL elements with the class ( '.' + selectedClass ), you should also check for same in your drop event.

Reason for that is that you arent really 'jquery-dragging' multiple items, you are just visually simulating it by moving around elements in unison, around the element that jquery would percieve as the element actually being dragged. If you run your fiddle with inspect on, you'll see your selected class toggle on all list elements as intented, but when you start to drag, only one element will contain the .ui-draggable-dragging class used by jquery.

Just by changing the identifier in the drop examplecode to selectedClass will enable you to find multiple id's, e.g.:

```
$.each($("."+ selectedClass), function(i, e) {
m_id.push(e.id);
alert(m_id);
});
```